# Combine subscribe and send from subject, why does order matter?

Tags: swift, combine

I can't understand why in this code, if I call `send` on the `subject` after the subject has been subscribed to `publisher`, it seems that the events are not received by the `subscriber`.

While if I move the `send` calls before the `subscribe` function all the items are listed (10,20,1,2,3)

```
    let publisher = [1,2,3].publisher
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let subscriber = subject.sink { print("value :\($0)")}

    publisher.subscribe(subject)
    subject.send(10)
    subject.send(30)
```

This prints

```
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
```

while this:

```
    let publisher = [1,2,3].publisher
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let subscriber = subject.sink { print("value :\($0)")}

    subject.send(10)
    subject.send(30)           
    publisher.subscribe(subject)
```

prints

```
value: 10
value: 30
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
```

Comment: Suprising. I would have thought the reverse: that the first prints all values and second code prints only 3 !  Order matters because If you subscribe to that subject after adding “10” and “30” using send(), you won’t receive these two values. You will just receive values that where sent after you subscribed to the Subject. See discussion here https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-master-%EF%B8%8F-the-basics-of-combine-in-5-minutes-639421268219

Comment: @claude31 I do not understand. Actually I'm subscribing to the subject BEFORE sending 10 and 30... but as you can see I've also create another subscription using sink. I do expect both the subscriptions to receive the events (from publisher and subject)

Comment: OK, you confirm that the logs you show correspond to the code above each, there is no inadvertent inversion. That is what is surprising effectively. It is normal that the result be different depending on the order of call. But I would have expected exactly the opposite: log #2 with code #1 and log #1 with code #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an implementation detail of whatever publisher is created off of a collection. In your first example, it's likely that the publisher doesn't actually care about subsequent values that come. It calls its own completion with `finished` after its own values are sent.

In your second example, you are pre-filling your subject with values. This is likely because the implementation of a collection's publisher appends its own values to whatever values are upstream at the time of subscription.

Why do you have your publisher subscribe to the subject, though? What is it you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think that you are right... the collection publisher just calls `finished` after it sends the last value. Hence the `subscription` is cancelled and when the other `send` messages are issued, the subscription is no longer available

Comment: To add some other info: it would be like calling `subject.send(completion: .finished)`